# Sql Server: How to display all master record for every child record?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have two tables one is master and other is child.

Something like this

Master:

```
Id  Description
1   Apple
2   Banana
3   Grape
4   Orange
```

Child:

```
Id  MasterFk    Date            Bought
1   2           01/Jan/2012     2
2   1           05/Jan/2012     4
3   4           06/Jan/2012     8
4   3           06/Jan/2012     10
5   1           09/Jan/2012     3
6   3           10/Jan/2012     5
```

Now I need data in this format

```
Date              Description    Bought
01/Jan/2012       Apple            0
01/Jan/2012       Banana          2
01/Jan/2012       Grape            0
01/Jan/2012       Orange          0
05/Jan/2012       Apple            1
05/Jan/2012       Banana          0
05/Jan/2012       Grape            0
05/Jan/2012       Orange          0
06/Jan/2012       Apple            0
06/Jan/2012       Banana          0
06/Jan/2012       Grape            10
06/Jan/2012       Orange          8
...
```

**Means all master data should be included in result for each date, if no corresponding data available in child it will show default value (0).**

Please help

Comment: So you are looking how to perform an inner join?

Comment: @cadrell0 - nope, an inner join won't return the output that he wants

Comment: Ah, I didn't look very close.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, assuming that you'll have only one record on your Child table that groups the total bought for a day, then you can do this:

```
SELECT Dates.[Date], M.Description, ISNULL(C.Bought,0) Bought
FROM MasterTable M
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT [Date] FROM ChildTable) Dates
LEFT JOIN ChildTable C
ON M.Id = C.MasterFk AND Dates.[Date] = C.[Date]
ORDER BY Dates.[Date], M.Description, C.Bought
```

If you can have more than just one record of a fruit for a day, then do the following:

```
SELECT Dates.[Date], M.Description, SUM(ISNULL(C.Bought,0)) Bought
FROM MasterTable M
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT [Date] FROM ChildTable) Dates
LEFT JOIN ChildTable C
ON M.Id = C.MasterFk AND Dates.[Date] = C.[Date]
GROUP BY Dates.[Date], M.Description
ORDER BY Dates.[Date], M.Description
```

Comment: +1... Same thing I was thinking... always looking for an excuse to show off a `CROSS JOIN`.

Comment: @MichaelFredrickson - I'm always cautious when showing a `CROSS JOIN` on an answer...the things I've seen when reviewing some querys that use a `CROSS JOIN`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Dates.date, m.description, ISNULL(c.bought,0)
FROM Master m
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT date FROM Child) Dates 
LEFT JOIN Child c ON c.MasterFK = m.Id and c.date = Dates.date
ORDER BY Dates.date
```

Answer (score 0):

this would be the "normal" way, but it wont  display the rows with 0 purchases:

```
Select c.date, m.description, c. bought
from Master m join Child c on m.id=c.masterid
order by c.date
```

if you really need those rows, the option is to have a "dates" table (or any other structure that can display all days in an interval - I once created a procedure that received 2 dates as parameters and returned a resultset with all the date between them, without weekends) and left join this structure with the previous select, like this:

```
Select d.date, m.description, c. bought
from Date D left join Child C on D.date=c.date join Master m on m.id=c.masterid
order by d.date
```

Comment: This won't return the values with zero `bought` for any day

Comment: you are right, I did not see that. Just corrected my answer, thanks for the heads up

Comment: @Diego - but what is the table `Date` in this context?

Comment: @Lamak I think he's saying have a `Date` table with all dates pre-poplated before the query... which might not be a bad thing to have if he wants to show totals for days in which no items were sold at all...

Comment: the table Dates could be populated by select distinct(date) from Child. See that he does not want all days, only the days that something was sold

Answer (score 0):

You should be cross joining all the possible dates w/ all the possible products, and then selecting out quantities bought that exist, if any for each combination.

Assuming table definitions:

```
create table Master (id int, description char(10));

insert into Master (id, description)
values (1, 'Apple'), (2, 'Banana'), (3, 'Grape'), (4, 'Orange');

create table Detail (id int, masterId int, buyDate date, bought int);

insert into Detail (id, masterId, buyDate, bought)
values (1, 3, '01/Jan/2012',     2),
   (2, 1, '05/Jan/2012',     4),
   (3, 3, '05/Jan/2012',     8),
   (4, 4, '09/Jan/2012',     10);
```

Use:

```
select BuyDates.BuyDate, M.description, 
       coalesce((select bought from Detail D
                 where D.buyDate = BuyDates.buyDate and M.id = D.masterId), 0)
from (select distinct buyDate from Detail) BuyDates
cross join Master M;
```